# layoutIfNeeded called on iOS10 but not iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am using `layoutIfNeeded` to do some view setup within a `UITableViewCell`. e.g.:

```
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
  super.layoutIfNeeded()
  let rescueButtonCornerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  let rescueButtonRoundedCornersPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rescueNowButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: MyTheme.cornerRadius, height: MyTheme.cornerRadius))
  rescueButtonCornerLayer.path = rescueButtonRoundedCornersPath.cgPath
  rescueNowButton.layer.mask = rescueButtonCornerLayer
}
```

This works fine in iOS10 however I've noticed `layoutIfNeeded` is not called at all in iOS9! Why is this? What can I do to get around it, or where should I place this setup code instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout code should be in `layoutSubviews`, which will be called automatically. You can also call `setNeedsLayout` and/or `layoutIfNeeded` to trigger layout, but you should not rely on either of those being called by anyone else.

Comment: Moved the code above to `layoutSubviews` which is indeed called on iOS9 and iOS10. However the button corners are not rounding at all. They only round if placed in `layoutIfNeeded`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @KexAri Did you check the bounds that you are setting in `layoutSubviews`, and the view hierarchy afterwards? Are you calling `super.layoutSubviews()`? Have you tried putting your own code on the other side (before vs after) of the `super` call?